# What rule prevents empty lines after the class opening brace?

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

I'm looking for a rule that prevents empty lines after the opening brace of a class.

I found the rule **Squiz.WhiteSpace.FunctionOpeningBraceSpace** for functions, but I can't find any for classes.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: There is no included rule that can enforce no empty lines at the start of a class definition.

Comment: Thanks @Greg Sherwood. Is there a documentation on how to write a rule?

Comment: There is a basic one here: https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Coding-Standard-Tutorial , but looking at existing sniffs would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**You are looking for `no_blank_lines_after_class_opening`** from [FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer).

If you want to use CodeSniffer, you still can. With [EasyCodingStandard](https://github.com/Symplify/EasyCodingStandard) you can use both.

```
# easy-coding-standard.neon
checkers:
    - PhpCsFixer\Fixer\ClassNotation\NoBlankLinesAfterClassOpeningFixer
```

Do you want more? [Check this short post](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/03/combine-power-of-php-code-sniffer-and-php-cs-fixer-in-3-lines/).

Comment: Thanks for this, but I don't want to use two tools. I use PHP_CodeSniffer in both PhpStorm and as a pipeline job in Gitlab. I want to write my own rule for this but didn't have the time yet.

Comment: I feel it the same way. It's one tool, both locally and on Github (Travis). PHP_CodeSniffer support in PHPStorm i s very limited and not flexible.  See [Travis](https://github.com/ApiGen/ApiGen/blob/3adb5e1085e208738b90caa5ff8809f003efdc31/.travis.yml#L19), with [composer.json](https://github.com/ApiGen/ApiGen/blob/3adb5e1085e208738b90caa5ff8809f003efdc31/composer.json#L69) setup